# String replacement in OCaml

Tags: regex, ocaml

This is part of my first OCaml program.

Its job is to replace a set of placeholder characters with umlauts. Taking the German word `Ruebe` as an example, the program turns it into `Rübe`. Other examples are `Moewe -> Möwe` and `aendern -> ändern`

Generally, everytime the program encounters the characters `ae`, `oe`, and `ue` it turns them into umlauts. There is an exception though: If the preceding character is a vowel, it does not change the word. This ensures words like `Treue` remain as they are (since there is no word `Treü`).

I've used the library [`Re2`](https://github.com/janestreet/re2) for regular expressions. `Re2` doesn't implement lookarounds, which was my first thought for checking for preceding vowels. This is the reason for the function `replace_if_not_after_vowel`.

I am happy for all suggestions, especially if they help make the code more idiomatic or simpler.

To compile the program, I used the command `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package re2 -package core -tag thread myCompiledFile.byte`

```
open Core.Std
open Re2.Std
open Re2.Infix

(* If the word contains an umlaut placeholder like "ue" we replace that with the proper umlaut "ü". Except if there is a vowel directly before the placeholder like in "Treue" *)
let placeholders_to_umlauts = [("ue", "ü"); ("oe","ö"); ("ae","ä"); ("Ue", "Ü"); ("Oe","Ö"); ("Ae","Ä")] 

(* A regex that matches a vowel *)
let vowel = ~/"[aeiou]"

(* Applies a list of changes to a word *)
let rec apply_changes word changes =
  match changes with
  | [] -> word
  | change :: rest -> apply_changes (change word) rest

(* Replaces replace_this with replacement inside the text if the preceding character not a vowel. Since Re2 doesn't implement lookarounds we can't use a negative lookbehind *)
let replace_if_not_after_vowel replace_this replacement text = 

  Re2.replace_exn ~/replace_this text ~f:(fun regex_match ->
   (* Returns true if there is a vowel at the given position in the text *)
   let is_vowel text pos = 
     if pos >= 0 && pos < String.length text then
       let maybe_vowel = String.get text pos in
       Re2.matches vowel (Char.to_string maybe_vowel)
     else false
   in

   (* Get the position in the text where the regex matched *)
   let match_pos, _ = Re2.Match.get_pos_exn ~sub:(`Index 0) regex_match in

   (* Replace the placeholder if doesn't follow a vowel *)
   if is_vowel text (match_pos -1 ) then replace_this else replacement
   )

let change_word word =
  (* Those are the changes that we will apply to the word *)
  let changes = List.map placeholders_to_umlauts ~f:(
    fun (placeholder, umlaut) -> replace_if_not_after_vowel placeholder umlaut
  )
  in

  apply_changes word changes

  let () =
    (* We want to change this word into "Übergrößenträgertreue" *)
    let word = "Uebergroeßentraegertreue" in
    let new_word = change_word word in 

    printf "new word: %s\n" new_word
```

Comment: Why not just update everything that matches [^aeyoiu] or begining of word, followed by `("ue"|"oe"|"ae"|"Ue"|"Oe"|"Ae","Ä")` ? You don't really need lookaround for that. At the moment, you are doing multiple regexp check, but you could do only one big.

Comment: Do you consider an exception dictionary?  Reading “Göthe” would be very strange! :)  Also, if you easily want to turn this in a standard Unix filter supporting filtering, reading files or in-place editing, you can try [Gasoline](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline), see the [caesar example](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline/blob/master/example/caesar/caesar.ml).

Comment: For anyone interested in a program performing such conversions, here's the repository to the OCaml code I currently use when writing in German with a non-German keyboard layout: https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/umlaut-conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Re](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re) version, since it was amusing to do. My version uses a slightly different technique: I build one big regexp, with two groups and replace everything in one go without any additional checking. If `Re.replace` provided slightly more control (per-group substitution) it would avoid the concatenation.

I used the combinators for building the regexp, instead of the symbolic version, because that's much more readable, really.

```
let map_to_umlauts =
  [ "ue","ü" ; "oe","ö" ; "ae","ä" ; "Ue","Ü" ; "Oe","Ö" ; "Ae","Ä" ]

let regexp =
  let open Re in compile @@
  seq [
    group @@ alt [ bow ; compl [no_case @@ set "aeiouy"] ] ;
    group @@ alt (List.map (fun (s,_) -> str s) map_to_umlauts) ;
  ]

let replace s =
  let f subs =
    Re.get subs 1 ^ List.assoc (Re.get subs 2) map_to_umlauts
  in
  Re.replace ~f regexp s

let () =
  print_endline @@ replace Sys.argv.(1)
```

On your version, apart from the change in algorithm, I have only one comment: You really don't need a regexp to check if a char is a voyel. ;)

Also, do note all of this is playing fast and, more important, very very loose, with Unicode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Me being new to OCaml I would very much appreciate it if you could explain what goes on in between `seq[...]`. Also, how could I make sure that this is safe regarding Unicode? I'd be happy about a general hint or link.

Comment: It's really just the equivalent of `([^aziouy]|bow)("ue"|"oe"|"ae"|"Ue"|"Oe"|"Ae")`, but written with Re's combinators. `seq` is a sequence, `alt` is alternative choices, `compl` is the complement. About Unicode ... I don't really know, unfortunately.